# How to convert from Hexadecimal to Decimal and from Decimal to Binary

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, converters

I would like how can I include the decimal result from the dance method to the light one. For example, in this program, if I input 5F, the decimal result would be 95. Well, I want that 95 to appear as a static int variable in the light method in order to be converted into a binary number. It would be also very helpful if you could tell me how can I limit the hexadecimal number to only 2 figures. Thanks for reading!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test2 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        DANCE(args);
        LIGHTS(args);
```

}

```
      public static void DANCE(String[]args) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter hex no:"+"");
            int no= Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine(), 16);
            System.out.println("Decimal no:"+no);
```

}

```
       public static void LIGHTS(String a[]){
                System.out.println("Binary representation: ");
                System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(no));
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names are written in camelCase.

Comment: Max 2 digit number in hex is FF which is 255 in decimal. You can limit input by checking that the decimal input is <= 255.

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful all your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

if you want to convert a hexadecimal value to a plain integer you can use:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("5F", 16);
System.out.println(i); // will print 95
```

And if you want your plain integer to be converted into a binary String you could use:

```
String j = Integer.toBinaryString(i); // from the above variable j which contains 95
System.out.println(j); // will print 1011111
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've understood how to make it. Thanks again :)